# jQuery hide checkbox if not checked on document start

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Hi I have a table with many different types of inputs and some of these being checkboxes.

I have limited users to checking 3 check boxes but allow them to edit the other check boxes. However on the page load I want the page to only show those check boxes that have been checked and to hide the others. So basically I would need to hide the table row called "contact_numbers" if it hasn't been checked.

I want this to be done on page load and not on click but I'm having some difficulty with this. If someone could point me into the right direction that would be great!

My code is below or view a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal90/hufLD/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.contact_no').attr('checked')) {
        $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').show()
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').hide()
    }
    $("input[class='contact_no']").change(function () {
        var maxAllowed = 3;
        var cnt = $("input[class='contact_no']:checked").length;
        if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
            $(this).prop("checked", "");
            alert('Select  ' + maxAllowed + ' telephone numbers, uncheck one box to check another!');
        }
    });
    $("#add").click(function () {
        $(".contact_numbers:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $(".contact_numbers").on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).closest('.contact_numbers').hide()
    });
});
```

Comment: Please reduce your demo to the minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem. We don't need to see *everything* (and it actively hinders us if we have to work out what's relevant); help us to help you, post only the minimal, relevant, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), necessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('.contact_no').each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $this.parents('tr.contact_numbers').show()
        } else {
            $this.parents('tr.contact_numbers').hide()
        }
    });
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hufLD/4/)

Comment: There are many of achieving this, but this was closest to what you were attempting at. Glad it was of help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$('.contact_no:not(:checked)').closest('.contact_numbers').hide();
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hufLD/6/)</kbd>